# How to add jquery UI icon for expand and collpase

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

How to add jquery UI icon for expand and collpase(toggled triangle image....ui-icon-triangle-1-s)

I have some  tags,once we click on, it should be expanding with tringle icon.
   tags are dashboard,task....

I tried added the following style..but no luck.

```
<span class="ui-accordion-header-icon ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s">
```

Please help me.

Here is fiddle [Accordion](http://jsfiddle.net/J5Hd4/8/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
$("#accordion").accordion(
    collapsible: true
    heightStyle: "content"
    icons:
        header: "ui-icon-arrowthick-1-e"
        activeHeader: "ui-icon-arrowthick-1-s");
});
});
```

And include the JQuery UI,and their CSS ,So refer this link http://jqueryui.com/accordion/.
Then use accordian functionality Instead of using your own slideDown(),Slideup()